# how to modify the value of hashmap in JavaScript according previous value

Tags: javascript, hashmap

If I would like to decrease the value of the hashmap by one from the previous value in javascript then what do I do?

```
var hash_A=new Map();

hash_A.set("a",5);
```

Comment: Note that you probably don't need a hashmap here? JS objects are already "named dictionaries", so ```const mything = {}; mything[`a`] = 5;``` gets you a perfectly usable object already, and ```thing[`a`] = (thing[`a`] ?? defaultValue) - 1;``` later on will work just fine.

Comment: thanks, Mike but I deliberately wanted to use hashmap in js

Comment: I'd be curious to know why, since a lot of the times that's something people new to JS want to do because they're used to how not-JS languages use associative arrays/hashmaps, and they don't (yet) know objects fill that role in JS.

Comment: I am solving some data structure problems where I have to use hashmap.

Answer (score 1):

```
let example = new Map()

example.set('value', 10) // set initial value
example.set('value', example.get('value') - 1) // override previous value
```